# Angular base64 video interpolation fail ($sce)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I'm trying to present a base64 video using Angular, only it fails to interpolate it due to $sce provider not trusting the source (which is a simple data url).

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{video}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  
URL: data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAGlzb21tcDQyAAAvzm1vb3YAAABsbXZoZ…+VXw5feXy+X3p3xV429Xirw87eVd0svWnUu3by8hW9zS6twXS5ZcbmgmlcKy+3CsI4raC9YA==
```

So far what I have tried:

```
$scope.video = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('base64-string-here');
```

This **didn't worked**, I believe the method is still expecting a valid link and not a data url, therefore it is not the right solution.

Second try:

```
angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
// Completely disable SCE.
// Do not use in new projects.
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

This of course **works**, but then it disables the entire provider, hence making the app vulnerable.

I have yet came across a valid solution for this, i'm displaying base64 images without any hassle so i'm sure there must be a way solve it, or at least a workaround.

Much thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a solution, here's my input 3 months after posting the question:

Base64 for videos is not a good idea, even if you solve the interpolation problem the app will crash on Android when played.

I spent a lot of time on it, so the solution on "how to play non-streamed videos on apps" is to:

1. Download the file to the local phone and play it from there (if you use angular then look for ngCordova file transfer plugin)
2. For Android: HTML5 video tag will **not work**. Reason is somewhere between permission issues and Android not allowing local videos to be played on HTML. Use an android video player such as [this media player](https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer)

For iOS: HTML5 video tag works perfectly well with playing local videos. It converts it with a native one.

Hope it helps somebody someday.